# What happens to NSF funding when someone passes away?

Tags: funding, united-states

A young professor at my old university recently passed away. They were still in the process of setting up their lab, taking on graduate students, etc.

What will happen to their NSF funding now? There is no obvious candidate in the department to take it over.

Comment: @DanRomik Well I didn't say it was a *large* concern. Just explaining what prompted my curiosity.

Comment: understood. I did not mean to sound critical of your curiosity - the question is a valid one.

Comment: @DanRomik - why not put the answer in the "answer" box?

Comment: The university could find a replacement professor to continue externally...

Comment: @DanRomik Your comment is totally unfair.  When a professor dies, his  students may be worried they will loose their only source of income, and with it the ability to finish their education.  That's hardly a trivial concern.  I think your comment verges on a personal attack on the asker, and it does sound critical.

Comment: @Anon I'm also thinking about the whole lab that was set up. Are they going to tear it down because the money's gone?

Comment: @DanRomik For the record, they passed a few months ago. I don't know whether that passes your threshold for idly wondering anonymously on the Internet about what happens to their funds.

Comment: @AzorAhai I don’t have a threshold. You can wonder about anything you like, and I’ve done my best to explain the context for my remark, but I can see that you still regard it as offensive or critical, so I’ll go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @DanRomik I did not take offense. I just wasn't sure what your point was - did you want me to remove the question?

Comment: It depends on whether the program officer believes that the university can find a way to deliver. They will probably want to support the students, but without a PI that can do the promised work, they might consider closing down the project. This being said, I expect some efforts to minimise the impact on people depending on the grant.

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends a bit on how accommodating the program officer is.  The money is allocated to the university and they can put a different PI on the project.  It seems likely to me that if students are depending on the funding, they should find a way to make it work but you never know with this stuff.  The onus would be on the university to come up with an acceptable alternate plan.